# Windows phone 8 app deployment without phone developer account for testing in other windows 8 phones

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, xap

Could you please guide me on how to deploy windows phone 8 apps on other windows phone for testing without phone developer account or any other means . Just deploy the .XAP in any other windows phone and test or for giving demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there can be many ways to deploy app on phone..
1. by launching a beta version of the app and giving microsoft account of the people you want to send it. it will be a 90 days trial and then app will be removed. while this you can also update your app for testers.

1. by using SD card. put your xap in sd card and then deploy on phone ...

here is the link which might help you

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402565(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: is there any process for launching beta version of the developed app? and also the second option which you gave doesn't work unless and until the app is in store for putting xap in sd card.

Comment: How can we release beta version for the app?

Comment: you will need a developer licence for that and then you can upload the the xap to the store as a beta version from your developer account and then in there you will have to add microsoft accounts of the people you want to test your app..

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769508%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) article, it describes the process. You need to register the phone, this process is now free. After the phone has been registered you can deploy apps to it using Visual Studio.

Comment: this process requires Windows Phone Developer Registration and u r saying it's free !